# Rails JSON query combined with other data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Contact model with a string and json attribute
the string attribute stores the phone_number and the json attribute stores some other data.

I want to run a query like this

```
Contact.exists?(phone_number: '+255788778899', data: {name: 'Gamma',   
region: 'The Great one'})
```

I have searched all over google and SO, but most of the articles simple give a way of find the record with a json string only and which has only one key

e.g

```
Contact.exists?("data ->> 'name' = 'Gamma'")
```

However my intention is to find if a contact exists with the phone number and the full json attribute specified in the same query

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish it is to use `where` and `present?` instead of `exists?`. For example:

```
Contact.where("data ->> 'name' = 'Gamma' AND phone_number = '+255788778899'").present?
```

The other benefit of this approach is if you're going to use the collection/object if it does exist, then you can first run the query:

```
@contacts = Contact.where("data ->> 'name' = 'Gamma' AND phone_number = '+255788778899'")
```

And then later, checking for its presence won't hit the database again:

```
@contacts.present?
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to use variables within your query, you can do so, but be sure to wrap them in quotes. For example:

```
name = 'Gamma'
phone = '+255788778899'
Contact.where("data ->> 'name' = '#{name}' AND phone_number = '#{phone}'")
```

Comment: this works great with the values hardcoded e.g data ->> 'name' = 'Gamma'

However if passing a variable it fails

irb(main):072:0> Contact.where("phone_number = #{@phone} AND data ->> 'name' = #{@name} AND data ->> 'region' = #{@region}")
  Contact Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE (phone_number = 2557812340003 AND data ->> 'name' = Gamma AND data ->> 'region' = Iringa)
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 1: SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE (msisdn = 25578123...

what could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, even though you may wrap the variable assignment in quotes (e.g. `@name = 'Gamma'`, the value within the query still needs to be wrapped in quotes (e.g. `'#{@name}'` not just `#{@name}`). Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about chaining it with a where clause like this:

```
Contact.where(phone_number: '+255788778899').exists?("data ->> 'name' = 'Gamma'")
```